# Recyclerview not being displayed when using API 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an android module (my own lib) which I'm using to fetch data from the web and display it as a list using recyclerview.

The data consists of paths to images which i'm loading via Picasso lib. Each item in the recyclerview list is an ImageView.

I am using androidx dependencies. The apps works as expected when installed in an emulator with API 24. However, the data is not displayed when the app is installed in an emulator with API 28.

I already debugged for API 28 and the data is fetcheda as expected.

**Here is where the list returns from the web as 'it'. When debugging, the list comes with 20 items as expected.**

```
viewModel.trendingsLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("trendingtitle", "trendingsLiveData.observe() called")
        allTrendingAdapter!!.loadItems(it)
        allTrendingAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        shimmerViewContainer?.stopShimmer()//stopShimmerAnimation()
        shimmerViewContainer?.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    })
```

**Line used to load images in the adapter (also checked with a breakpoint  - working as expected)**

```
Picasso.get().load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${results!!.get(position).poster_path}").into(holder.poster);
```

**Build.gradle (my Android Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


def moshiVersion="1.8.0"
def retrofit2_version = "2.5.0"
def okhttp3_version = "3.12.0"
def kotlinCoroutineVersion = "1.0.1"
def picassoVersion = "2.71828"

//ViewModel Scope
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'

//recyclerview
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

//Moshi
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

//Retrofit2
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2_version"
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2"
//Because of an error with JAR version
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:'1.3.31'"

//Okhttp3
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

//Picasso
implementation ("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picassoVersion"){
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}

implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
}
```

**Build.gradle (Module app)**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':posterlistlib')
}
```

**Build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Why is the list of images being displayed in API 24, but is not in API 28?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the images not loading, replace `http://image.tmdb.org` with `https://image.tmdb.org`

Answer (score 3):

For simple fix please use below code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   ...>
```

From API 28, URL with HTTP won't work by default, for more details on this topic check below link

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Comment: Do note that various app scanners such as Play Protect may mark your app as harmful/insecure. For a MUCH better answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493322/3999808

Comment: I just changed the right answer because it's more secure. But both allow the app to display the desired data.